# How to keep up when converting between bases?

Tags: signal-processing, information-theory, computational-mathematics

Here is a schematized binary channel
that neatly conveys a decimal number.
$
\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\def\T    {{ \cal T }}
\def \Ti  {{  \T \raise5mu{ \text- \scriptsize 1 } }}
\def\Bx #1{{ ~ \rightarrow ~ \boxed{\, #1 \,\Large\strut} \: \rightarrow ~ }}
\def \BTi {\Bx {      \kern 1mu            \Ti \kern1mu }}
\def  \BT { \Bx{ \rlap{\kern6mu \T} \phantom\Ti         }}
$

$$     123_{(10)}  \BT  1111011_{(2)}
  \BTi 123_{(10)}
$$

But how to keep up with an endless *stream* of decimal digits?

$$      1, \,   2, \,   3, \, \ldots _{\,  (10)}
  \BT       \ldots  \,  ?      \ldots _{\,  (2)}
   \BTi 1,   \, 2,   \, 3,   \, \ldots _{\,(10)}
$$

[Binary coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)
with 4 bits for each decimal digit works readily:

$$        1, \,     2, \,     3, \, \ldots _{\,  (10)}
  \BT  0001   ~  0010   ~  0011   \, \ldots _{\,  (2)}
   \BTi   1,   \,   2,   \,   3,   \, \ldots _{\,(10)}
$$

Yet this wastes the binary channel's capacity,
with a bitwise efficiency of just $ \, \frac{\log_2 10}{4} = 0.83^+ $.
The waste can be reduced with larger groupings,
such as coding 3 digits at a time with 10 bits
for an efficiency of
$ \, \frac{\log_2 1000}{10} = \frac{3}{10} \, \log_2 10 = 0.996^+ $,
which remains measurably less than $1$ and increases maximum
[lag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29)
from 4 bits to 10 bits.

**Is there a straightforward algorithm pair**, $\T$ and $\,\Ti$,
with bounded lag, that is asymptotically wasteless
when given an input stream of evenly random decimal digits?

$$ \dfrac
   {\small\text {cumulative number of decimal digits conveyed}}
   { \small\text{cumulative number of bits used in transmission}} ~ {\log_2 10}
   {\large~\xrightarrow{\quad}~} 1
$$

<sub>Please ground any algorithms in terms of specific bases,
not necessarily decimal and binary, perhaps ternary and binary,
that are not rational powers of each other.
A general solution would be easy enough to gather from that.
This is an inquiry into ideal,
not just efficient,
conversion of information.</sub>

---

**Addenda**

Another straightforward suboptimal approach is to
[Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)
each digit as in the following table.
This has a respectable average efficiency of
$ \, \frac{1}{3.4} \, \log_2 10 = 0.977^+ $
and maximum lag of 4 bits.

$$ \small \begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
 \rm   Decimal   &   0 &   1 &   2 &   3 &   4 &   5 &    6 &    7 &    8 &    9
\\\rm  Binary    & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 1100 & 1101 & 1110 & 1111
 \\\rm Bit~count &   3 &   3 &   3 &   3 &   3 &   3 &    4 &    4 &    4 &    4
  \\[1ex]
     \rm \rlap{Average~bit~count~~~~3.4} & & & & & & &      &      &      &
\end{array} $$

Any table-lookup encoding, such as every approach mentioned above,
will indeed have bounded lag but nonetheless be measurably inefficient.

An optimally efficient approach with *unbounded* lag,
as commented by
[leonbloy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815451#comment3714460_1815451),
is [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding),
which interprets sequences as fractions
that readily convert between decimal and binary.
The potential for unlimited lag can be seen
already in the first decimal digit, below,
as the binary transmissions for
$ \, 5,9,8, \ldots _{\, (10)} \, $
and
$ \, 6,0,0, \ldots _{\, (10)} \, $
are indistinguishable until the 9<sup><sub>th</sub></sup> bit.

$$
          5,9,8, \ldots _{\,  (10)}
  \Bx{~ 0.598       ...     _{(10)} = 0.100110010..._{(2)} \raise-6mu\strut~}
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0, \ldots _{\, (2)}
\\[3ex]
          6,0,0, \ldots _{\,  (10)}
  \Bx{~ 0.600       ...     _{(10)} = 0.100110011..._{(2)} \raise-6mu\strut~}
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1, \ldots _{\, (2)}
\endgroup $$

Comment: Can you transmit them right to left?

Comment: Now I think my idea won't work, sorry.

Comment: I doubt there's any algorithm with bounded lag and asymptotically no waste. No matter how many bits you look at, there will be some ambiguity in the binary equivalent.

Comment: The optimal way would be with arithmetic coding. But the lag is unbounded.

Comment: Related paradoxical question: Does perfectly accurate transmission with unbounded lag amount to information loss? The arithmetic coding example can be extended to 5,9,9,9,... vs 6,0,0,0,..., both being transmitted as 1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,... indefinitely without a single decimal digit actually being conveyed.

Comment: You may want to look at O. Shayevitz et al.  "Delay and Redundancy in Lossless Source Coding," in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 60, no. 9, pp. 5470-5485, Sept. 2014. and references within.